# Can a Horizontal asymptote occur for all $\lim_{x\to \infty}$

Tags: limits

What is the cases that we use with it a horizontal asymptote ?
I mean is it always we use a horizontal asymptote we use $\lim_{x\to \infty}$

limit as $f\left(x\right)=\:\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}$ can not be $1$ which in this case it's obvious to use horizontal asymptote

But there is also some other functions like
$\:f\left(x\right)=\left(\frac{−3}{7}x\right)$ which f(x) \begin{bmatrix}\mathrm{Solution:}\:&\:-\infty \:<f\left(x\right)<\infty \\ \:\mathrm{Interval\:Notation:}&\:\left(-\infty \:,\:\infty \:\right)\end{bmatrix}

which not clear to use with it a horizontal asymptote !

what make me ask this Question is in my james book it defend a horizontal asymptote as :

> The line $y=L$ is called a horizontal asymptote of the curve $y=f(x)$
>   if either
>
> $\lim \:_{x\to \:\infty \:\:}f\left(x\right)\:=\:L\:$
>
> or
>
> $\lim \:\:_{x\to \:\:-\infty \:\:\:}f\left(x\right)\:=\:L$

It's looks like a general definition for horizontal asymptote to use it with $\lim_{x\to \infty}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Horizontal asymptotes are found by $\lim_\limits{x \to \infty}f(x)$ and $\lim_\limits{x \to -\infty}f(x)$ given that they exist.

As an example, you have a rational function $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ in which the two polynomials have the same degree:

$$f(x) = \frac{a_1x^n+b_1x^{n-1}+c_1x^{n-2}+…+z_1}{a_2x^n+b_2x^{n-1}+c_2x^{n-2}+…+z_2}$$

As $x \to \infty$, $a_1x^n$ and $a_2x^n$ quickly outgrow the rest of the terms, leaving $\frac{a_1x^n}{a_2x^n}$, so $\lim_\limits{x \to \pm\infty}f(x) = \frac{a_1}{a_2}$, which becomes the horizontal asymptote. This is usually shown through factoring and noting that $\frac{c}{x} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ for constant $c$:

$$f(x) = \frac{\left(a_1+\frac{b_1}{x}+\frac{c_1}{x^2}+…+\frac{z_1}{x^n}\right)}{x^n\left(a_2+\frac{b_2}{x}+\frac{c_2}{x^2}+…+\frac{z_2}{x^n}\right)} = \frac{a_1+\frac{b_1}{x}+\frac{c_1}{x^2}+…+\frac{z_1}{x^n}}{a_2+\frac{b_2}{x}+\frac{c_2}{x^2}+…+\frac{z_2}{x^n}}$$

$$\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to \pm \infty}\frac{a_1\color{blue}{+\frac{b_1}{x}+\frac{c_1}{x^2}+…+\frac{z_1}{x^n}}}{a_2\color{blue}{+\frac{b_2}{x}+\frac{c_2}{x^2}+…+\frac{z_2}{x^n}}} = \frac{a_1\color{blue}{+0+0+…+0}}{a_2\color{blue}{+0+0+…+0}} = \frac{a_1}{a_2}$$

Hence, for [$f(x) = \frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/r0y3tp2qm0), the horizontal asymptote becomes $\frac{1}{1} = 1$.

Your second example involves a [linear function](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nnzl1utlor). A linear function has no asymptotes because its range is $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_\limits{x \to \pm \infty} f(x)$ is not a finite value.  You’re looking for a value that $f(x)$ tends to as it approaches infinity or negative infinity, but that value may not always exist.

Sometimes, a function might have two horizontal asymptotes. An example of this is $f(x) = \frac{3x+2}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}$. To find the horizontal asymptotes, you use the normal process:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{3x+2}{\sqrt{x^2-4}} = \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x\left(3+\frac{2}{x}\right)}{\sqrt{x^2\left(1-\frac{4}{x^2}\right)}} = \frac{x(3+0)}{\sqrt{x^2(1+0)}} = \frac{3x}{\sqrt{x^2}}$$

Recalling $\sqrt{x^2} = x$ for $x \geq 0$, the first horizontal asymptote becomes $y = \frac{3x}{x} = 3$. To find the second horizontal asymptote, you need $\lim_\limits{x \to -\infty} f(x)$:

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to -\infty}\frac{3x+2}{\sqrt{x^2-4}} = \lim_{x \to -\infty}\frac{x\left(3+\frac{2}{x}\right)}{\sqrt{x^2\left(1-\frac{4}{x^2}\right)}} = \frac{3x}{\sqrt{x^2}}$$

Recalling $\sqrt{x^2} = -x$ for $x < 0$, the second horizontal asymptote becomes $y = \frac{3x}{-x} = -3$. [Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rn16nhb7yq) is the plot.

You can use the same process for other functions you are given.

Comment: You right about function $f\left(x\right)=\left(\frac{−3}{7}x\right)$  it's range is not finite, but what about linear function with slope 0 it's have any horizontal asymptote?

Comment: More precisely, since its limits to infinity are divergent, there is no horizontal asymptote.

Comment: I didn’t see your other question. A constant function in the form $f(x) = c$ may be thought of as asymptotic to itself since the line lies on the asymptote itself I guess, but there really is no point in considering it as such.

Comment: @KM101- Yes, You right, i just want to knew if we let limit x to infinity with  A constant function in the form $f(x)=c$ could it have horizontal asymptote, This is for me tricky since if Yes , then a horizontal asymptote can cross the graph of function infinite many of times !   any way Thanks for helping me. Vote Up and accepted answers.

Comment: I’m glad the answer helped!

Answer (score 0):

There are functions like $f(x)=\arctan(x)$ which have *two* horizontal asymptotes. Here both $y=\pi/2$ [as $x \to \infty$] and $y=-\pi/2$ [as $x \to - \infty$] are asymptotes. It can be seen by reflecting the graph of $\tan(x)$ on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ through the line $y=x.$

Another case for your question is $g(x)=e^x.$ It has $y=0$ as a horizontal asymptote, but only as $x\to -\infty.$ It gives an example where one cannot just consider $x \to \infty.$ [Here the limit as $x \to \infty$ is $\infty,$ not a number $L$ as required in the book you mention.